# Displaying double-quotes from text box in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have written a small JSP page that contains a text box and a button. What I am attempting to do is to display whatever I have written in the text box (which is a String) once i click the button. It has worked for all scenarios but did not work for the one scenario where I put the string within **double quotes** (" "). Is there any way I can make that work?

***For example***: If I write **abcd** within the text box, it works fine. But if I write **"abcd"** (i.e with double quotes), then the text within the double quotes don't display.

I understand why that is happening (example: If we write **abcd** in the text box, it is taken as **"abcd"** and if I write **"abcd"** within the text box, it is taken as **""abcd""**), but couldn't find a solution for that.

**Or is there a solution for that at all?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes - escape the quotes. You should replace them with `&quot;`

A ready-to-use solution that will cover some more cases is commons-lang `StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(str)`

Comment: @hari: The key here is that the text in attributes is marked up like all other HTML text, so you use the entity for a double quote. (This is also why the `&` in query strings in `href` attribute values **should** always be escaped, e.g. `href="page.jsp?foo=1&bar=2"` is wrong, although browers try to help you out if they can; it *should* be `href="page.jsp?foo=1&amp;bar=2"`.)

Answer (score 1):

Hey try this it will work fine without any other libraries:

for example:

In jsp file,

```
<form action="Login">
        Enter :<input type="text" name="txtStr"></input>
        <input type="submit" name="btnGo" value="Go"></input>
</form>
```

In Servlet,

```
String str = request.getParameter("txtStr");    
System.out.println("helo : " + str);

request.setAttribute("str", str);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/dis.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In dis.jsp;

```
<body>
    ${str}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) to escape HTML..

Use `escapeHtml(String str)` function to escape HTML characters..

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(str)
```